# How to iterate through JProperties of JObject key with JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

In JSON.net, how do you iterate through the JProperties of a JObject key's children?

Code:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonstring);
var developments = json["Developments"][0];

//Doesn't work
//Error   CS1929  'JToken' does not contain a definition for 'Properties' and the best extension method overload 'Extensions.Properties(IEnumerable<JObject>)' requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable<JObject>'
//foreach(JProperty property in development.Properties())
//    Console.WriteLine(property.Name + property.Value);
```

JSON:

```json
{
  "Developments": {
    "Plot 125": {
      "developer": "XYZ",
      "selection":{
        "Subdivision 1" : "135000",
        "Subdivision 2":  "450000"
      }
    },
    "Plot 126":{
      "developer": "XYZ",
      "selection":{
        "Subdivision 1": "56000",
        "Subdivision 2": "98000",
        "Subdivision 3": "456000"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

<sub>Compiled with JSON.net 4.0 version 6.0.0</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All `JToken` objects contain properties that allow you to operate on any object as if it were any of the valid json types.

In json.net in particular, the children of objects are `JProperty`. So just get the children of the object.

```
var query =
    from x in json["Developments"].Children<JProperty>()
    select x.Name;
```

On the other hand, if it is already typed as a `JObject`, you could access the properties directly.

```
var query =
    from x in ((JObject)json["Developments"]).Properties()
    select x.Name;
```